# How can you set a file handle to be used within a class in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm not sure I'm asking my question correctly. I want to be able to open a file in the constructor of my class and use it within all of the class functions. The following doesn't work though.  I get the following warnings and my member variables aren't set.

```
[26-Sep-2020 09:05:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in D:\Plesk\Vhosts\idolpx.com\c64.idolpx.com\api\fs_t64.php on line 20
[26-Sep-2020 09:05:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, int given in D:\Plesk\Vhosts\idolpx.com\c64.idolpx.com\api\fs_t64.php on line 22
[26-Sep-2020 09:05:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, int given in D:\Plesk\Vhosts\idolpx.com\c64.idolpx.com\api\fs_t64.php on line 24
[26-Sep-2020 09:05:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, int given in D:\Plesk\Vhosts\idolpx.com\c64.idolpx.com\api\fs_t64.php on line 26
[26-Sep-2020 09:05:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, int given in D:\Plesk\Vhosts\idolpx.com\c64.idolpx.com\api\fs_t64.php on line 27
[26-Sep-2020 09:05:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in D:\Plesk\Vhosts\idolpx.com\c64.idolpx.com\api\fs_t64.php on line 32
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is this not possible?
Here is my class.  Please advise.

```
class FS_T64 extends FS_Native {
    public $signature;
    public $version;
    public $dir_max;
    public $dir_count;
    public $header;
    
    private $fp;

    function __construct( $image )
    {
        if(file_exists($image) == 1)
        {
            $this->$fp = fopen($image, 'rb');
            
            $this->$signature   = fread($this->$fp, 32);    // Get Signature
            $bytes              = fread($this->$fp, 2);     // Tape Version
            $this->$version     = ord($bytes[0]) + (ord($bytes[1]) * 0x100);
            $bytes              = fread($this->$fp, 2);     // Max Directory Entries
            $this->$dir_max     = ord($bytes[0]) + (ord($bytes[1]) * 0x100);
            $bytes              = fread($this->$fp, 2);     // Total number of used Directory Entries
            $this->$dir_count   = ord($bytes[0]) + (ord($bytes[1]) * 0x100);
            $unused             = fread($this->$fp, 2);     // Unused bytes
            $this->$header      = fread($this->$fp, 24);    // Tape container name
        }
    }
    
    function __destruct() {
        fclose($this->fp);
    }
    

    function sendHeader()
    {
        global $url;
        global $path;
        global $image;
        
        // Send List HEADER
        $this->sendLine(0, sprintf("\"%-19s\" T64", $this->$header), "NFO" );
        
        // Send Extra INFO
        $this->sendLine(0, sprintf("\"%-19s\" NFO", "[URL]"), "NFO" );
        $this->sendLine(0, sprintf("\"%-19s\" NFO", $url), "NFO" );
        if (strlen($path) > 1)
        {
            $this->sendLine(0, sprintf("\"%-19s\" NFO", "[PATH]"), "NFO" );
            $this->sendLine(0, sprintf("\"%-19s\" NFO", $path), "NFO" );
        }
        if (strlen($image) > 1)
        {
            $this->sendLine(0, sprintf("\"%-19s\" NFO", "[IMAGE]"), "NFO" );
            $this->sendLine(0, sprintf("\"%-19s\" NFO", $image), "NFO" );
        }
        $this->sendLine(0, "\"-------------------\" NFO", "NFO" );  
    }

    function sendListing() 
    {
        $this->sendHeader();
        
        // Read Directory Entries
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $this->$dir_count; $i++)
        {       
            $ft_c64s = fread($this->$fp, 1);    // C64s filetype (0 = free, 1 = Normal, 3 = Snapshot, 2-255 Reserved)
            $file_type = fread($this->$fp, 1);  // 1541 filetype (0x82 = PRG, 0x81 = SEQ, etc.)
            $start_address  = fread($this->$fp, 2); // Start address
            $start = ord($start_address[0]) + (ord($start_address[1]) * 0x100);
            $bytes     = fread($this->$fp, 2);  // End address
            $end = ord($bytes[0]) + (ord($bytes[1]) * 0x100) + (ord($bytes[3]) * 0x1000) + (ord($bytes[4]) * 0x10000);
            $unused  = fread($this->$fp, 2);    // Unused bytes
            $bytes  = fread($this->$fp, 4); // Offset from beginning where file starts
            $offset = ord($bytes[0]) + (ord($bytes[1]) * 0x100) + (ord($bytes[3]) * 0x1000) + (ord($bytes[4]) * 0x10000);
            $unused  = fread($this->$fp, 4);    // Unused bytes
            $filename = fread($this->$fp, 16); // C64 filename padded with $20 (spaces)
            $length = $end - $start;
            
            switch ( $file_type )
            {
                case 0x80;
                    $type = "DEL";
                    break;
                    
                case 0x81;
                    $type = "SEQ";
                    break;

                case 0x82:
                    $type = "PRG";
                    break;
                
                case 0x83;
                    $type = "USR";
                    break;
                    
                case 0x84;
                    $type = "REL";
                    break;
            }
            
            $blocks = $length / 256;
            $blocks = $length / 256;
            $block_spc = 3;
                if ($blocks > 9) $block_spc--;
                if ($blocks > 99) $block_spc--;
            $line = sprintf("%s%-18s %s", str_repeat(" ", $block_spc), "\"".strtoupper($filename)."\"", $type);
            $this->sendLine( $blocks, $line, $type );
        }
        
        $this->sendFooter();
    }

    function sendFooter()
    {
        $this->sendLine( 65536, "BLOCKS FREE", "NFO" );
        echo "\n"; // Empty line to indicate end of directory   
    }

    function seekFile( $filename )
    {
        // Read Directory Entries
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $this->$dir_count; $i++)
        {       
            $ft_c64s = fread($fp, 1);   // C64s filetype (0 = free, 1 = Normal, 3 = Snapshot, 2-255 Reserved)
            $ft_1541 = fread($fp, 1);   // 1541 filetype (0x82 = PRG, 0x81 = SEQ, etc.)
            $start_address  = fread($fp, 2);    // Start address
            $start = ord($start_address[0]) + (ord($start_address[1]) * 0x100);
            $bytes     = fread($fp, 2); // End address
            $end = ord($bytes[0]) + (ord($bytes[1]) * 0x100) + (ord($bytes[3]) * 0x1000) + (ord($bytes[4]) * 0x10000);
            $unused  = fread($fp, 2);   // Unused bytes
            $bytes  = fread($fp, 4);    // Offset from beginning where file starts
            $offset = ord($bytes[0]) + (ord($bytes[1]) * 0x100) + (ord($bytes[3]) * 0x1000) + (ord($bytes[4]) * 0x10000);
            $unused  = fread($fp, 4);   // Unused bytes
            $entry = trim(fread($fp, 16)); // C64 filename padded with $20 (spaces)
            $length = $end - $start;
            
            if ($entry == $filename )
            {
                fseek($this->$fp, $offset);
                return Array( 'start'=>$start_address, 'length'=>$length );
            }
        }
    }

    function sendFile( $filename )
    {
        $ra = $this->seekFile( $filename );
        
        //Set Content Type
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

        //Use Content-Disposition: attachment to specify the filename
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));

        //No cache
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');

        //Define file size
        header('Content-Length: ' . $ra['length']);

        ob_clean();
        flush();
        echo $ra['start'];
        fpassthru($this->$fp);
    }
}

$fileSystem = new FS_T64("$root$path$image");
$fileSystem->sendListing();
```

Comment: Your code would benefit from some simple error handling. Try checking the result of `fopen()` for `FALSE`. `error_get_last()` is probably also a function you want to use to see what happens. You could also start by checking the contents of `"$root$path$image"` which is the filename that you're feeding to `fopen()`. Might it be that you're assuming a trailing slash where there isn't one?

Comment: change any occurrence of: `$this->$someproperty` to `$this->someproperty` : e.g.`$this->$fp` to `$this->fp`, `$this->$signature` to `$this->signature` etc.

Comment: @lovelace OMG! duh... thank you.  I kept staring at this wondering why it wasn't working.

Comment: @RoAchterberg yep... I do need to add some error handling. Was just trying to get it working first. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @lovelace Please post as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

## Declare properties

When you want to add a [property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) to a class, first set its [visibility](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) level, i.e.: `public`, `private`, or `protected`, followed by the property name, which must always be preceded by a `$` sign.

e.g.: `public $name`

You can also initialize properties at the time you declare them:

e.g.: `public $name = ''; // defaults to empty string.`

And, starting PHP7.4, you can use [typed class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php):

e.g.: `public string $name = ''; // typed property, defaults to empty string.`

which enforces `$name`  can only be assigned `string` values.

## Access properties

The correct syntax for accessing object properties: `$object->property`

A small example:
You'd like to access a property `public $firstName` of `class User`:

```
<?php
$user = new User(); // instantiate - create an object
$user->firstName; // access property firstName
```

Note that the property-name is not preceeded by a `$` symbol.

### $this

*The pseudo-variable $this is available inside any class method when that method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object* (source: [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) ).

So, if you want to access a property from within your class, use: `$this->property`

example:

```
<?php
class User
{
    public string $user = '';

    public function setUser(string $user): void
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function getUser(): string
    {
        return 'user : ' . $this->user;
    }

    /*
     * other class stuff
     */

}

$user = new User();
$user->setUser('Patrick');
echo $user->getUser(); // output: user: Patrick
```

### Static properties in a Class

If you want to declare static class properties(class-level properties), you use e.g.:

`public static int $counter;`

To access `$counter`, use: `ClassName::$counter`

> **Notice**, here the property-name *is* preceded by a `$` sign.

If you refer to a static property from inside a class, you'd use the `self` keyword:
`self::$count`

Again, here, the property-name *is* preceded by a `$` sign.

```
<?php
class User
{
    public static int $count = 0;

    public function getCount(): string
    {
        return 'count : ' . self::$count;
    }

    /*
     * other class stuff
     */

}

User::$count++;
echo User::$count; // output: 1
$user = new User();
echo $user->getCount(); // output: count: 1
```